# Node.js: instantiate an object with data taken from a database async query

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, oop, mongoose

I'm trying to replicate a common design pattern used by many PHP frameworks where the properties of a class are populated with live data taken from the database. For example, you pass an ID to the constructor of the Product class and the class properties are filled with the related database fields. The problem I'm encountering is basically due to the asynchronous nature of database queries in Node.js. Either you choose callbacks or Promises or even the latest and (IMHO) exciting features of async/await, you have always to deal with a new scope where the binding to the main object is gone. If you can point me to the right direction, I'll surely appreciate it very much.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Trying to replicate PHP in Node is probably going to lead you to insanity.  Plus, I would argue that just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you should.  In every language I've worked in, what you're describing has been considered a bad idea if for no other reason than you should make potentially time-consuming operations like DB queries a bit more explicit, rather than implicit.  Even frameworks that used to make heavy use of lazy loading from the DB typically recommend against that approach for anything but prototyping.

Comment: Hey man, pretty much everything that you'll need to write in Node.js will probably be asynchronious. Not only the DB queries. Also requests to the server, any file read/write etc etc. So you shouldn't be worried that you have to do the `await` to get the data out of the DB. Or do `.then` whatever. You'll do lot's of awaits/thens anyway. Would you mind to provide the example code where you are losing the scope and the bindings are gone?